How to cut floor tile for bathtub curves
What is the best method to cut the curves around the tub? We aren’t sure what tile we will use for the floor, but it will be either of these two. I’ve seen a Dremel be used but on whole tile and not mosaic.



Just an update. I found it easiest to move the sheet of tile to cut as close as I could to my traced curve on the sheet of tile. To stop the individual tile from buckling, I use a wood backer board that I cut a kerf into. So the tile saw could go pass through tile without cutting into the wood.  I used a file to clean up any areas. I was able to get the curve pretty tight and caulk hid any imperfections. Overall the floor came out good for my first small format tile. Hopefully this helps others as well!


The tool you are looking for is called a tile nipper. It's sold at hardware stores. It does the job.

I thought about that but it doesn’t seem like I could get a clean enough cut. Although maybe the caulk would hide any imperfection since it will be along the tub?

It works remarkably well. The grout does the rest.

@Cheery don't you mean "caulk?"

@Huesmann I meant grout. The tiles don't go right against the tub, but about 1/8" should be left for grout. So the grout is what follows the contour of the tub. Then some silicone-based caulk on top.

Another solution is gritted-rod hacksaw blade. May be easier for a novice to follow a complicated line with than nippers
